# What is SQL Server 2005 expected behavior of insert into table select query where one of the columns attempts to convert a null value

Tags: sql-server-2005, null, type-conversion, sql-insert

We have a statement in some legacy SQL Server 2005 code like

```
insert into myTable
select distinct 
   wherefield1, 
   wherefield2,
   anotherfield,
   convert(numeric(10,2), varcharfield1),
   convert(numeric(10,2), varcharfield2),
   convert(numeric(10,2), varcharfield3),
   convert(datetime, varcharfield4),
   otherfields
from myStagingTable
where insertflag='true'
and wherefield1 = @wherevalue1
and wherefield2 = @wherevalue2
```

Earlier in the code, a variable is set to determine whether varcharfield1 or varcharfield2 is null, and the insert is programmed to execute as long as one of them is not null.

We know that if varcharfield1, varcharfield2, or varcharfield3 is a nonnumeric character string, an exception will be thrown and the insert will not occur.  But I am perplexed by the behavior when one of these variables is null, as it often is.  Actually, it is always the case that one of these values is null.  But it seems that the insertion does take place.  It looks like the legacy code relies on this to prevent only insertion of nonnumeric character data, while allowing insertion of null or empty values (in an earlier step, all empty strings in these fields of myStagingTable are replaced with null values).

This has been running on a Production SQL Server 2005 instance with all default settings for a number of years.  Is this behavior we can rely on if we upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server?

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conversion of `NULL` to anything is still `NULL`. If the column allows `NULL`, that's what you'll get. If the column is not nullable, it will fail.

You can see this yourself without even doing an INSERT. Just run this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(10,2), NULL)
```

and note how it produces a `NULL` result. Then run this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric(10,2), 'x')
```

and note how it throws an error message instead of returning anything.

Comment: You are correct, of course.  Attempted conversion of nulls had been suggested by a colleague as the cause of a buch of error log entries, but those turned out to be caused by attempted conversion of nonnumeric character strings.  It was only later I realized the author of the code had converted empty values to nulls specifically to avoid causing an error, and left the nonnumeric character string conversion error uncaught in order to prevent insertion and force review of the data by human eyeballs.